# How to override set_login in spree model user.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, model, spree

In spree sign_up the `app/models/spree/user.rb` has

```
def set_login
  # for now force login to be same as email, eventually we will make this configurable, etc.
  self.login ||= self.email if self.email
end
```

How can I override set login and do something like this:

```
def set_login
  # for now force login to be same as email, eventually we will make this configurable, etc.
  self.login ||= self.phone if self.phone
end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this in app/models/spree/user_decorator.rb

```
 Spree::User.class_eval do
    Spree::PermittedAttributes.user_attributes << :phone


 def set_login
   # for now force login to be same as email, eventually we will make this configurable, etc.
   self.login ||= self.phone if self.phone
 end
end
```